# Strange boo language syntax

Tags: closures, boo

I've run into a strange syntax in [Boo Language Guide](http://boo.codehaus.org/Closures) :

```
setter = { value | a = value }
```

What does the | operator mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation of Boo seems to be lacking in this area -- it seems that

```
setter = { value | a = value }
```

is shorthand for

```
setter = def(value):
    a = value
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, having never used Boo, my (educated) guess is that it's for passing parameter to the closure lambda-style functions. In this case, { p | C } refers to an anonymous function taking a single parameter bound to p within the code C.

Answer (score 2):

Adam is correct. The point of the example is to show that lambdas in boo have read and write access to enclosing scope.

Answer (score 0):

That syntax for specifying code blocks (anonymous functions) has been borrowed from [Ruby](http://blog.codahale.com/2005/11/24/a-ruby-howto-writing-a-method-that-uses-code-blocks/) and [Smalltalk](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~harry/musings/SmalltalkOverview.html#Blocks)